# Como pasar esta logica aplicada con setstate a provider?

Tags: flutter, content-provider

llevo dias con este problema estoy aprendiendo provider y se basicamente como usarlo. pero me gustaria pasar este codigo a provider pero no se de que forma hacerlo.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool isActive = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5.0,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: 200.0,
          height: 250.0,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 155.0,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      imageUrl: url,
                      placeholder: (context, urlImage) =>
                          Container(color: Colors.grey),
                      errorWidget: (context, urlImage, error) =>
                          Center(child: Container(color: Colors.grey)))),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ubicacion != ""
                          ? Text(ubicacion,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                              maxLines: 1)
                          : Container(),
                      titulo != ""
                          ? Text(titulo,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              maxLines: 2)
                          : Container(),
                      precio != ""
                          ? Text(precio,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              maxLines: 1)
                          : Container(),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: isActive? const Icon(Icons.favorite,
                           color: colors.red,
                           )
                           : const Icon(
                           Icons.favorite_border,
                           color: colors.red,
                           ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              isActive = !isActive;
                            });
                          },
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

sinceramente no puedo aplicar esta logica con provider. he hechos otros cambios de estados
como contadores cambiar un valor de color pero cuando uso esta logica aplicada a provider
todos estos iconos comparten el mismo estado.
les agardeceria mucho. saludos

Comment: Ya te comenté lo que tenías que hacer en la anterior pregunta... Si no te ves preparado para hacer algo así, ¿no sería recomendable que busques algún curso para aprender Flutter? No te lo tomes a mal, en ningún momento, quiero ofender. Pero lo que pides es relativamente sencillo de hacer y si no eres capaz, seguramente es porque te faltan bases de conocimiento. Te recomendaría que sigas algún curso gratuito/pagado de Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

La forma de cambiar la lógica a provider es la siguiente:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        IsActiveProvider isActiveProvider = Provider.of<IsActiveProvider>(context);
    return Card(
      elevation: 5.0,
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
      child: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: 200.0,
          height: 250.0,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: 200.0,
                  height: 155.0,
                  child: CachedNetworkImage(
                      fadeInDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      imageUrl: url,
                      placeholder: (context, urlImage) =>
                          Container(color: Colors.grey),
                      errorWidget: (context, urlImage, error) =>
                          Center(child: Container(color: Colors.grey)))),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      ubicacion != ""
                          ? Text(ubicacion,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.grey[600]),
                              maxLines: 1)
                          : Container(),
                      titulo != ""
                          ? Text(titulo,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              maxLines: 2)
                          : Container(),
                      precio != ""
                          ? Text(precio,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              maxLines: 1)
                          : Container(),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: IconButton(
                          icon: isActiveProvider.isActive? const Icon(Icons.favorite,
                           color: colors.red,
                           )
                           : const Icon(
                           Icons.favorite_border,
                           color: colors.red,
                           ),
                          onPressed: () {
                              isActiveProvider.isActive = !isActiveProvider.isActive;
                          },
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IsActiveProvider with ChangeNotifier{

    bool _isActive = false;
    
    bool get isActive{
        return _isActive;
    }

    set isActive(bool value){
        isActive = value;
        notifyListeners();
    }
    
}
```

Como ves, la forma de cambiarlo es convirtiendo la propiedad `isActive` en una propiedad de la clase del `Provider`. Los `setState` se cambian por el setter que ya redibuja el widget gracias a la función `notifyListeners`
Para utilizar un provider también debes agregarlo en un nivel superior en tu árbol de widgets, en este caso podríamos hacerlo en el archivo main.

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => IsActiveProvider(),
    ),
  ],
child: MaterialApp(...)
)
```

Comment: te agradezco mucho pero en realidad al dar el toque no funciono. Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#1707f

Comment: Considero que esta respuesta no es correcta. El creador de la pregunta está pidiendo un ejemplo de cómo tener los estados de los iconos por separados. Lamentablemente, el título de se pregunta no concuerda con lo que realmente está pidiendo. Tu ejemplo, actualmente, modificaría todos los elementos pues compartirían el mismo provider, que está inyectado de forma global. De todos modos, te doy mi +1.